# Best way to share a git repo between home and work PCs?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, git

I have a git repo on both my home and work computer. Both of these repos get pushed to a TFS server via git-tfs, but that's irrelevant. The big problem I'm having is because I can't just push to the main repo it's not easy to share unpushed work between my home and work computers. So, I need some way of sharing a git repo from my work computer to my home computer. Both are running Windows 8 and have cygwin configured(which is how I use git). What is my best bet for this? Ideally, it'd require very little setup and be simple to do a "one-off" sync

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way that's reasonably secure but is really "the Linux way" (kind of hard to avoid since you're using a program whose Windows "port" is not really a native port):

1. Set up an SSH server on one box that gives you the Cygwin shell (openssh-server)
2. Make sure you have port forwarding set up or a static IP so your SSH server is listening on the public internet
3. Use `git push` from your client box to your server using the protocol schema `ssh://` and your auth details.

Comment: I didn't know there was a (good) SSH server for Windows heh.

Comment: http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html

Comment: http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a webservice, [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) is hard to beat for simplicty. It works with either Git or Mercurial, and it's free. It also has an excellent [setup tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+101), though given the content of your post, you may be beyond needing it =).

Comment: I'd love to use bitbucket(it's where I host most stuff), but it's proprietary code that my company doesn't want to host outside of the company